# C# generic with constant

Tags: c#, c++, security, templates, generics

Is there something similar to this C++ template?

```
template <int A>
class B
{
    int f()
    {
        return A;
    }
}
```

I want to make every instance of B<1>, B<2>, etc (eg tuple) a different type.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

The short answer is **no**.

It doesn't fit the way C# generics, as apposed to C++ templates, work.

The .net generics are not a language feature, they are a runtime feature. The runtime knows how to instantiate generics from special generic bytecode which is rather restricted compared to what C++ templates can describe.

Compare this with C++ templates, which basically instantiate the whole AST of the class using substituted types. It'd be possible to add AST based instantiation to the runtime, but it'd certainly be much more complex than the current generics.

Without features like value-type arrays (which only exist in unsafe code), recursive template instantiation or template specialization using such parameters wouldn't be very useful either.

Comment: Well, at runtime (JIT) .Net makes the instantiation. Instantiation is essentially duplication with modifications. I would not oppose AST to MSIL as much. Different representation of similar concepts.

Answer (score 23):

A workaround to this limitation is to define a class which itself exposes the literal value you are interested in. For example:

```
public interface ILiteralInteger
{
   int Literal { get; }
}

public class LiteralInt10 : ILiteralInteger
{
   public int Literal { get { return 10; } }
}

public class MyTemplateClass< L > where L: ILiteralInteger, new( )
{
   private static ILiteralInteger MaxRows = new L( );

   public void SomeFunc( )
   {
      // use the literal value as required
      if( MaxRows.Literal ) ...
   }
}
```

Usage:

```
var myObject = new MyTemplateClass< LiteralInt10 >( );
```

Comment: A dirty workaround, but a clever one. Unfortunately, that's the only way for now

Answer (score 14):

C# does not support non-type generic parameters like C++ does.

C# generics are far simpler and less capable than C++ templates.  MSDN has a succinct list of [Differences Between C++ Templates and C# Generics](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c6cyy67b.aspx).

Comment: However, additional information can be "encoded" into types (by contract definition or otherwise), it's simple to see with a fixed set of discreet types (e.g. `Vn : V, where Vn.Value = n for all Vn`), but there is also [church numerals](http://community.bartdesmet.net/blogs/bart/archive/2009/08/17/mis-using-c-4-0-dynamic-type-free-lambda-calculus-church-numerals-and-more.aspx) -- not that I recommend *either approach* here :-)

Comment: Not an incorrect answer, but it would be nice if it provided a link to C# generics and/or talked about generic declaration/"instantiation" vs. template instantiation.

Comment: @pst:  Sure; you can encode information into types.  You can also avoid generics altogether and write lots of nongeneric classes.  In any case; I added a link to the MSDN article enumerating the major differences between templates and generics.

Answer (score 5):

C# generics are specialized at run-time, whereas C++ templates are processed at compile-time to make an entirely new type. Given this, the runtime simply doesn't have the features to process non-type parameters (it's not just a C# issue).

Answer (score 3):

With C# 10, there's something that comes sort of close:

```
interface IConstant
{
    abstract static int Constant { get; }
}

class B<T> where T : IConstant
{
    int GetConstant() => T.GetConstant();
}

class Constant1 : IConstant { static int Constant => 1; }
class Constant2 : IConstant { static int Constant => 2; }
```

This does not guarantee that `Constant` is actually constant sadly, and you need to define types for all numbers you want to use. However it does allow you to discriminate `B<Constant1>` and `B<Constant2>`

Not nearly an equivalent but something at least

Note that you need to add `<EnablePreviewFeatures>true</EnablePreviewFeatures>` to your .csproj for this to work, as `abstract static` Interface methods are still in preview

Answer (score 0):

The following approach may be useful depending on what you're trying to accomplish. The size of the underlying collection is determined by an abstract property.

```
public abstract class TupleBase
{
    protected abstract int NumElems { get; }
    protected object[] values;

    protected TupleBase(params object[] init)
    {
        if (init.Length != NumElems)
        {
            throw new ArgumentException($"Collection must contains {NumElems} elements", nameof(init));
        }
        values = new object[NumElems];
        for (int i = 0; i < init.Length; i++)
        {
            values[i] = init[i];
        }
    }

    protected object Get(int idx) => values[idx];
    protected void Set(int idx, object value) => values[idx] = value;
}

public class Tuple1<T> : TupleBase {
    protected override int NumElems => 1;
    public Tuple1(T val0) : base(val0) { }
    public T Get0() => (T)Get(0);
    public void Set0(T value) => Set(0, value);
}

public class Tuple2<T, U> : TupleBase {
    protected override int NumElems => 2;
    public Tuple2(T val0, U val1) : base(val0, val1) { }
    public T Get0() => (T)Get(0);
    public U Get1() => (U)Get(1);
    public void Set0(T value) => Set(0, value);
    public void Set1(U value) => Set(1, value);
}

public class Tuple3<T, U, V> : TupleBase
{
    protected override int NumElems => 3;
    public Tuple3(T val0, U val1, V val2) : base(val0, val1, val2) { }
    public T Get0() => (T)Get(0);
    public U Get1() => (U)Get(1);
    public V Get2() => (V)Get(2);
    public void Set0(T value) => Set(0, value);
    public void Set1(U value) => Set(1, value);
    public void Set2(V value) => Set(2, value);
}

public class Tuple4<T, U, V, W> : TupleBase
{
    protected override int NumElems => 4;
    public Tuple4(T val0, U val1, V val2, W val3) : base(val0, val1, val2, val3) { }

    public T Get0() => (T)Get(0);
    public U Get1() => (U)Get(1);
    public V Get2() => (V)Get(2);
    public W Get3() => (W)Get(3);
    public void Set0(T value) => Set(0, value);
    public void Set1(U value) => Set(1, value);
    public void Set2(V value) => Set(2, value);
    public void Set3(W value) => Set(3, value);
}

public class Tuple5<T, U, V, W, X> : TupleBase
{
    protected override int NumElems => 5;
    public Tuple5(T val0, U val1, V val2, W val3, X val4) : base(val0, val1, val2, val3, val4) { }
    public T Get0() => (T)Get(0);
    public U Get1() => (U)Get(1);
    public V Get2() => (V)Get(2);
    public W Get3() => (W)Get(3);
    public X Get4() => (X)Get(4);
    public void Set0(T value) => Set(0, value);
    public void Set1(U value) => Set(1, value);
    public void Set2(V value) => Set(2, value);
    public void Set3(W value) => Set(3, value);
    public void Set4(X value) => Set(4, value);
}
```