# C# - Nestable, bounded arrays

Tags: c#, typedef, pascal

I'm porting a game written in Pascal (compiled in 16 bit) to C# (so it will run on machines newer than XP).  From what I've gathered, in Pascal, it's possible to type define in the type section of a unit/program through syntax like this:

```
type
    BaseArrayPtr = ^BaseArray;
    BaseArray = array [1 .. 5, 1 .. 5] of Integer;

    SubArray = array [0 .. 3] of BaseArray;
```

I also gathered that, unfortunately, it is impossible to type define in C#.  However, I'm trying for a workaround.  So far, this is what I have:

**BoundedArray.cs:**

```
using System;
using System.Collections;

namespace test
{
    abstract class BoundedArray<T>
    {
        public BoundedArray()
        {
            m_data = null;
        }

        public T this[params int[] index]
        {
            get
            {
                if (index.Length != m_data.Rank)
                    throw new IndexOutOfRangeException();

                return (T) m_data.GetValue(index);
            }
            set
            {
                if (index.Length != m_data.Rank)
                    throw new IndexOutOfRangeException();

                m_data.SetValue(value, index);
            }
        }

        protected void SetAttributes(int[] lowerBounds, int[] lengths)
        {
            if (lengths.Length != lowerBounds.Length)
                throw new ArgumentException();

            m_lowerBounds = lowerBounds;
            m_lengths = lengths;

            m_data = Array.CreateInstance(typeof(T), m_lengths, m_lowerBounds);
            m_data.Initialize(); // Should (but doesn't) initialize every element in m_data
        }

        Array m_data;
        int[] m_lengths;
        int[] m_lowerBounds;
    }
}
```

**test.cs:**

```
using System;

namespace test
{
    class Program
    {
        public static int[] ints(params int[] values)
        {
            return values;
        }

        class BaseArray : BoundedArray<int>
        {
            public BaseArray()
            {
                SetAttributes(ints(2, 2), ints(1, 2));
            }
        }

        class SubArray : BoundedArray<BaseArray>
        {
            public SubArray()
            {
                SetAttributes(ints(4), ints(2));
            }
        }

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            SubArray subArray = new SubArray();

            Console.Read();
        }
    }
}
```

I've checked `baseArray`, and the default values of `m_data` are zeroes, since they are `int`s.  However, in `subArray`, the default values of `m_data` are null - the `BaseArray` instances inside the array in `subArray` haven't been initialized for some reason.  How do I get the default constructor to run?

EDIT: The real question at the moment is why doesn't `m_data.Initialize();` in the `SetAttributes` method initialize all elements in `m_data`?  [The documentation on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.array.initialize.aspx) seems to indicate that it should...

EDIT:
So I believe that problem is that `System.Array.Initialize` only works on value-types.  Since classes are references types in C#, `System.Array.Initialize` doesn't do anything.  So I have to find a way to initialize a reference-type array of variable dimensions, lengths, and lower bounds.

Comment: What did you try?Did you find any solutions

Comment: No, I haven't found a solution.  The documentation for `System.Array.Initialize` seems to indicate that it should do exactly what I need, but as you can see, I have it in there, and it doesn't do anything...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've already answered my own question once, but I came up with a **much** better implementation of my answer.

Here's what this solution consists of:

1. `SetAttributes` must be run once, in the default constructor of a class based off of `BoundedArray`
2. During `SetAttributes`, I gather a jagged, two-dimensional array of all of the indices in the current `BoundedArray` subclass
3. I create instances of the template type by calling `Activator.CreateInstance` and assigning one per index

Other things to note:

- Set attributes now takes a variable length array of `int[]`s instead of two `int[]`s.  Previously, it was taking the lowerbounds and the lengths, but I realized it makes more sense to just take `int[]`s which are lower and upper bounds, and then use a LINQ query to check that there aren't any which aren't pairs
- I created a static class called `IntArray`, which is used extensively by `SetAttributes` and in **test.cs**
- I tried to throw as many useful errors as possible, since I'll probably end up using this code a lot
- I have a feeling that `Combinations(int[][] list1, int[] list2)` is probably where the most improvement on my solution could be found.  I'm open to suggestions on how to improve all of my code

So, without further ado, my complete solution:

**BoundedArray.cs**

```
using System;
using System.Linq;
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace test
{
    static class IntArray
    {
        public static int[] FromValues(params int[] values)
        {
            return values;
        }

        public static int[] Sequence(int from, int length)
        {
            if (from < 0 || length < 1)
                throw new ArgumentException();

            return Enumerable.Range(from, length).ToArray();
        }

        public static int[][] Combinations(int[] list1, int[] list2)
        {
            return Combinations(list1.Select(i => new int[] { i }).ToArray(), list2);
        }

        public static int[][] Combinations(int[][] list1, int[] list2)
        {
            List<List<int>> result = new List<List<int>>();

            for (int i = 0; i < list1.Length; i++)
            {
                for (int j = 0; j < list2.Length; j++)
                    result.Add(((int[]) list1.GetValue(i)).Concat(new int[] { list2[j] }).ToList());
            }

            return result.Select(i => i.ToArray()).ToArray();
        }
    }

    abstract class BoundedArray<T>
    {
        public BoundedArray()
        {
            m_data = null;
        }

        public Array Value
        {
            get { return m_data; }
        }

        public T this[params int[] index]
        {
            get
            {
                if (index.Length != m_data.Rank)
                    throw new IndexOutOfRangeException();

                return (T) m_data.GetValue(index);
            }
            set
            {
                if (index.Length != m_data.Rank)
                    throw new IndexOutOfRangeException();

                m_data.SetValue(value, index);
            }
        }

        protected void SetAttributes(params int[][] values)
        {
            // Make sure all of the values are pairs
            if (values.Where(i => i.Length != 2).ToArray().Length > 0)
                throw new ArgumentException("Input arrays must be of length 2.");

            int[] lowerBounds = values.Select(i => i[0]).ToArray();
            int[] lengths = values.Select(i => i[1] - i[0] + 1).ToArray();

            m_data = Array.CreateInstance(typeof(T), lengths, lowerBounds);

            int[][] indices = (lowerBounds.Length != 1) ?
                IntArray.Combinations(IntArray.Sequence(lowerBounds[0], lengths[0]), IntArray.Sequence(lowerBounds[1], lengths[1]))
                : IntArray.Sequence(lowerBounds[0], lengths[0]).Select(i => new int[] { i }).ToArray();

            for (int i = 2; i < lowerBounds.Length; i++)
                indices = IntArray.Combinations(indices, IntArray.Sequence(lowerBounds[i], lengths[i]));

            for (int i = 0; i < indices.Length; i++)
                m_data.SetValue(Activator.CreateInstance(typeof(T)), indices[i]);
        }

        Array m_data;
    }
}
```

**test.cs**

```
using System;

namespace test
{
    class Program
    {
        // *** Examples of what you can do with BoundedArray ***

        // Multi-dimensional, bounded base array
        class BaseArray : BoundedArray<int>
        {
            public BaseArray()
            {
                SetAttributes(IntArray.FromValues(2, 3), IntArray.FromValues(2, 4));
            }
        }

        // One-dimensional, bounded subclass array
        class SubArray : BoundedArray<BaseArray>
        {
            public SubArray()
            {
                SetAttributes(IntArray.FromValues(4, 6));
            }
        }

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            // Initializations used for testing purposes
            BaseArray baseArray = new BaseArray();
            SubArray subArray = new SubArray();

            // Example of assignment
            baseArray[3, 4] = 3;
            subArray[4][2, 3] = 4;

            subArray[4][2] = 3; // Weakness: compiles, but causes IndexOutOfRangeException

            Console.Read();
        }
    }
}
```

Thougts?

Answer (score 0):

You have a singe-dimensional array `SubArray` which holds `BaseArray` objects which are two-dimensional arrays of intergers. In place of Pascal `type`, you can define a custom C# class which would override the [indexer operator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa288465%28v=vs.71%29.aspx) to give you exactly the same behavior.

**EDITED** 
So, in Pascal you have this:

```
type
    BaseArrayPtr = ^BaseArray;
    BaseArray = array [1 .. 5, 1 .. 5] of Integer;

    SubArray = array [0 .. 3] of BaseArray;
```

Maybe I misunderstood the question, but is the below not exactly the same, in C#?

```
public class BaseArray
{
    int[,] m_array = new int[5, 5];

    static void CheckBounds(int x, int y)
    {
        if (x < 1 || x > 5 || y < 1 || y > 5)
            throw new IndexOutOfRangeException();
    }

    public int this[int x, int y]
    {
        get 
        {
            CheckBounds(x, y);
            return m_array[x-1, y-1]; 
        }
        set 
        {
            CheckBounds(x, y);
            m_array[x-1, y-1] = value; 
        }
    }
}

public class SubArray
{
    BaseArray[] m_array = new BaseArray[4];

    public BaseArray this[int x]
    {
        get { return m_array[x]; }
        set { m_array[x] = value; }
    }
}
```

Comment: I know.  That's what I'm doing so far.  The problem is that the elements of `SubArray` aren't being instantiated.

Comment: @BrianGradin, I updated my answer. Did I misunderstand your question?

Comment: @BrianGradin, I guess I see what you mean now: it's [impossible](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4636512/c-sharp-generic-with-constant) to use `int` as argument in generics. In which case, my answer doesn't apply.

Comment: skimming through your code, it looks like it might do what I'm trying to do, but I would rather base both `BaseArray` and `SubArray` off of the same class - `BoundedArray`.  That way, it makes the class definitions for `BaseArray` and `SubArray` much more concise, as you can see in **test.cs** in the edited original problem

Answer (score 0):

Well I have done some changes that when you want to create an instance of a `SubArray` you should pass `BaseArray` as source of data to be initialize.

As i understood you want to set the values from `BaseArray` to `SubArray`.

Here is my work:

**BoundedArray.cs**

```
 abstract class BoundedArray<T>
{
    public BoundedArray()
    {
        m_data = null;
    }

    public int[] Lengths;
    public int[] LowerBounds;

    public void CreateInstance()
    {
        if (Lengths.Length != LowerBounds.Length)
            throw new Exception("Incorrect number of lengths or lower bounds.");

        m_data = Array.CreateInstance(typeof(T), Lengths, LowerBounds);
    }
    public void CreateInstance(Array source)
    {
        if (Lengths.Length != LowerBounds.Length)
            throw new Exception("Incorrect number of lengths or lower bounds.");

        m_data = Array.CreateInstance(typeof(T), Lengths, LowerBounds);

        /************************************************************************/
        /*    Now you should find the value of BaseArray and set it to m_data                                                                     */
        /************************************************************************/


    }
    public T this[params int[] index]
    {
        get
        {
            if (index.Length != m_data.Rank)
                throw new IndexOutOfRangeException();

            return (T)m_data.GetValue(index);
        }
        set
        {
            if (index.Length != m_data.Rank)
                throw new IndexOutOfRangeException();

            m_data.SetValue(value, index);
        }
    }
    public Array GetData()
    {
        return m_data;
    }
    Array m_data;
}
```

**Test.cs**

```
class Program
{
    public static int[] ints(params int[] values)
    {
        return values;
    }

    class BaseArray : BoundedArray<int>
    {
        public BaseArray()
        {
            Lengths = ints(1, 2);
            LowerBounds = ints(2, 2);

            CreateInstance();
        }
    }

    class SubArray : BoundedArray<BaseArray>
    {
        public SubArray(BaseArray arr)
        {
            Lengths = ints(2);
            LowerBounds = ints(4);

            CreateInstance(arr.GetData());
        }
    }

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        BaseArray baseArray = new BaseArray();
        SubArray subArray = new SubArray(baseArray);

        Console.Read();
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm not trying to assign the data to whatever data is in `BaseArray` - I'm just trying to instantiate each element of `m_data` in `SubArray`.

Comment: how do you want to instantiate the `SubArray` do you want to set it's values to zero

Comment: Not necessarily.  I want to run the default constructor on whatever happens to be in the array (which, in this case, are elements of `BaseArray`)

Comment: Ohh well after `Array.CreateInstance` you should do some code in which default constructor of each element applies.

Comment: `initialize()` function does not work because i think you have not declare one for it!