# Unity/C#: Class specialization by value (equivalent to C++ std::array<int>)

Tags: c#, c++, templates, generics, unity-game-engine

I have a problem that I know how to solve in C++, but I don't know how this works in C#. Here is a sample code in C#:

```
public class TowerTile<ScriptType, SpriteName> : Tile where ScriptType : MonoBehaviour {
    private void Awake() {
        gameObject = new GameObject();
        gameObject.AddComponent<ScriptType>();
        colliderType = Tile.ColliderType.None;
        sprite = GameManager.shared.sprites[SpriteName];
    }
}
```

The `SpriteName` from the example should be of type string so I could use it in `operator[]` on `Dictionary<string, Sprite> sprites`.

Here is how I would write it in C++:

```
template <typename ScriptType, typename SpriteRef = std::string> 
class TowerTile : public Tile {
    private void Awake() {
        gameObject = new GameObject();
        gameObject.AddComponent<ScriptType>();
        colliderType = Tile.ColliderType.None;
        sprite = GameManager.shared.sprites[SpriteRef];
    }
}
```

How can I achieve this in C#? I can't pass the string in as a constructor argument because these Tile objects are instantiated with `ScriptableObject.CreateInstance<T>()`, which can't pass any constructor arguments.

Comment: So you want to pass a string literal as type parameter?

Comment: Yep. That's what I would like to be able to do.

Comment: C# doesn't support that. You could check out this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/32694825/4187549

Comment: I've already seen that and that frankly it is terrible solution. The way I've solved it for now is that `ScriptType` conforms to `ITowerAI` that has a property 'sprite' which I use at the end of 'Awake' function here. This binds the sprite used to AI used, but it's the best I came up with.

Comment: How about this?: https://answers.unity.com/questions/310847/how-to-create-instance-of-scriptableobject-and-pas.html

Comment: Hmm, the factory pattern could certainly work. I'll give it a try, thanks for help. This would also solve my problem Unity not being able to instantiate a generic object in code required to create instance of Tile.

Answer (score 1):

To make the question and answer more clear, I wanted to template this class from example because the way it was instantiated in Unity with `ScriptableObject.CreateInstance<T>()` didn't allow for constructor arguments. Even if the specialization by value was possible in C# (which is not), it wouldn't help either because the instatiating method can't create generic types anyway (why Unity?). So my solution to I've used is a factory with a templated method that returns base class 'Tile'.

```
public class TileFactory {
    private TileFactory() {}

    public static Tile CreateInstance<ScriptType>(string spriteName) where ScriptType : DefaultAI {
        var tile = ScriptableObject.CreateInstance<TowerTile>();
        tile.sprite = GameManager.shared.sprites[spriteName];
        tile.gameObject.name = spriteName;
        tile.gameObject.GetOrAddComponent<ScriptType>();
        return tile;
    }
}
```

**Changes from the example in question are:**

- Problem of not being able to pass `spriteName` into `ScriptableObject.CreateInstance<T>()` is solved by wrapping this method in my own factory method.
- `ScriptableObject.CreateInstance<T>()` is called with non-generic type and only after is added the generic type script to the object.
- Returned instance is also a non-generic type which as it seems Unity has some problems with for some reason.
- `ScriptType` now should be of base `DefaultAI` which is of base `MonoBehaviour` (not really relevant for the purposes of this answer).

Another option would be to use a `Buidler` but since I only needed to pass 1 required argument, builder wouldn't make much sense. In some other cases though it is would be a better solution.

*p.s.:* Thanks to Furkan Kambay for providing relevant sources that helped solve this issue