# Give arguments to custom model binder

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5

I'm writing asp.net mvc 5 web api. I have the following code and I want to call the web api like http://localhost/API/Compatibility/59dd2c60-c340-4735-8ecb-85efc60c7b14;d126d9b3-4516-46ca-bd6c-1a8c23740b90

```
[RoutePrefix("API/Compatibility")]
public class CompatibilityController : ApiController
{
    [Route("{organizationIds}")]
    public Guid Get(IList<Guid> organizationIds)
    {
        ...
    }
}
```

Currently parameter `organizationIds` cannot receive the values from URL. I understand it's because default model binder doesn't know how to separate GUID.

Custom model binder seems the rescue.

My other web api may use different separator other than semicolon. Therefore rather than create `SemicolonSeparatedBinder`, `CommaSeparatedBinder`, `PipeSeparatedBinder`, and so forth, can I create `SymbolSeparatedBinder` and pass in the separator?

Is it possible to do like this?

```
[Route("{organizationIds}")]
public Guid Get([ModelBinder(typeof(SymbolSeparatedBinder), separator=";")]
                IList<string> organizationIds)
{
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out another way by using `ParameterBindingAttribute` and `HttpParameterBinding`.

```
/// <summary>
/// Applies to an Array type, specifies the string that is used to split elements.
/// </summary>
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Parameter, AllowMultiple = false)]
public class ArraySeparatorAttribute : ParameterBindingAttribute
{
    string _separator;

    public ArraySeparatorAttribute(string separator)
    {
        _separator = separator;
    }


    public override HttpParameterBinding GetBinding(HttpParameterDescriptor parameter)
    {
        if (typeof(System.Collections.IEnumerable).IsAssignableFrom(parameter.ParameterType))
            return new ArraySeparatorParameterBinding(parameter, _separator);
        throw new NotSupportedException($"{nameof(ArraySeparatorAttribute)} can only be applied to array.");
    }
}

internal class ArraySeparatorParameterBinding : HttpParameterBinding
{
    string _separator;

    public ArraySeparatorParameterBinding(HttpParameterDescriptor parameter, string separator) : base(parameter)
    {
        _separator = separator;
    }

    public override Task ExecuteBindingAsync(ModelMetadataProvider metadataProvider, HttpActionContext actionContext, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        string separatorListString = (string)actionContext.RequestContext.RouteData.Values[Descriptor.ParameterName];
        var elements = separatorListString.Split(new string[] { _separator }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);


        ValueProviderResult r = new ValueProviderResult(elements, null, System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);

        actionContext.ActionArguments[Descriptor.ParameterName] = r.ConvertTo(Descriptor.ParameterType);


        var tsc = new TaskCompletionSource<object>();
        tsc.SetResult(null);
        return tsc.Task;
    }
}
```

Usage is like this

```
[RoutePrefix("API/Compatibility")]
public class CompatibilityController : ApiController
{
    [Route("{organizationIds}")]
    public Guid Get([ArraySeparator(";")] Guid[] organizationIds)
    {
        return Guid.NewGuid();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`ModelBinder` attribute requires the type of the binder. The best solution here would be generic class parametrized with constant character, e.g. `SymbolSeparatedBinder<','>`, `SymbolSeparatedBinder<';'>`. However C# [does not support](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4636512/c-sharp-generic-with-constant) this unlike C++.

You still have simple and elegant solution for this problem. Define basic `SymbolSeparatedBinder` class with abstract `Separator` property that should be overridden with specific separator characters:

```
public abstract class SymbolSeparatedBinder : IModelBinder
{
    protected abstract char Separator { get; }

    public bool BindModel(HttpActionContext actionContext, ModelBindingContext bindingContext)
    {
        //  Put all logic here. Use Separator property for splitting.
        //  ...

        return true;
    }
}

public class SemicolonSeparatedBinder : SymbolSeparatedBinder
{
    protected override char Separator => ';';
}

public class CommaSeparatedBinder : SymbolSeparatedBinder
{
    protected override char Separator => ',';
}

[Route("{organizationIds}")]
public Guid Get([ModelBinder(typeof(CommaSeparatedBinder))]
                IList<string> organizationIds)
{
    ...
}
```

With such solution you avoid duplication of binding code. The only drawback is necessity to declare a class for each supported separator.

Comment: Thanks. I figured out another solution myself.